# AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin does not load the icon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a plug-in where I have added icons to the icon folder.
Then get icons image in following way

```
AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, pIconPath).createImage()
```

It's working fine when I run my plug-in via Eclipse run configuration, but doesn't work (null pointer exception) when I install my plug-ins standalone in Eclipse.

My `build.properties` file is

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/
```

So, the icons folder is included.

My path to the icon is like following

> icons/prod/Commands_Prod_icon.png

Where am I wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure, does `PLUGIN_ID` denote the same plug-in that contains the image?

Comment: Images not working in the exported plugin is usually a problem in the build.properties but this looks OK here. Check the plugin jar to see if the icons directory has actually been included.

Comment: I have check, everything is fine: ID is right, image is present. But it's don't work, why?

Comment: Just as a sanity check, does your path have any leading characters, as noted here: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin.html#imageDescriptorFromPlugin

Comment: Are you calling this method in the same plugin, or from a different plugin?